# How to create dynamic objects inside dynamic objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object, state

This is created another objects dynamically when you click a button. But I want to create new object inside questions Array when I click a button.

```
const [inputFields, setInputFields] = useState([
    {
      sectionName: "",
      sectionDesc: "",
      questions: [{ questionType: "", questionText: "" }],
    },
  ]);
const handleChange = (index: any, event: any) => {
    const values = [...inputFields];
    // @ts-ignore
    values[index][event.target.name] = event.target.value;
    setInputFields(values);
    console.log(index, event.target.name);
  };

const handleAddFields = () => {
    setInputFields([
      ...inputFields,
      {
        sectionName: "",
        sectionDesc: "",
        questions: [{ questionType: "", questionText: "" }],
      },
    ]);
  };
```

Comment: `values[index][event.target.name] = event.target.value;` this mutates the object in state. To add to the `questions` array, you need to know with object in the `inputFields` array first, then simply spread into the relevant `questions` array.

Comment: firstly, the state is array, when you click function handleAddFiedls, it create new objects in array. But I want to create objects inside questions Array without changing data inside objects in state for example: [
    {
      sectionName: "",
      sectionDesc: "",
      questions: [{ questionType: "", questionText: "" }, { questionType: "", questionText: "" }],
    },
  ]

Comment: It looks like you have a number of questions that all have useful answers that you haven't responded to. see: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Accepting an answer makes the question more useful to the general community by making it a valid duplicate target.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you are mutating state in your `handleChange` handler. You can avoid this using `map()`

```
const handleChange = (index: number, event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
  setInputFields(prev => prev.map((p, i) => (
    i === index
      ? {
        ...p,
        [event.target.name]: event.target.value
      }
      : p
  )));
};
```

As for adding to the `questions` array, you will need an index for *which* object you want to add to, then use the same technique as above to spread into that object.

```
const handleAddFields = (index: number) => {
  setInputFields(prev => prev.map((p, i) => (
    i === index
      ? {
        ...p,
        questions: [...p.questions, { questionType: "", questionText: "" }]
      }
      : p)
  ));
};
```

*Note: Using `any` for all parameters defeats the purpose of typing, try to use relevant types to take advantage of the type system.*